# Python not equating empty cell with ""

Tags: python, pandas

Python noob here. I am working on a project and I am getting some strange results. I have managed to duplicate the results in a small example. I saved the following in Excel as a csv file:

```
var 1,var 2
20,a
10,a
,a
5,a
4,a
0,a
1,a
21,a
```

I am trying to count how many empty pieces of data there are (i.e. 1)

```
test = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
print(test[test["var 1"]==""].count())
test["var 1"].replace("", "Unknown", inplace=True) 
print(test[test["var 1"]==""].count())
print(test[test["var 1"]=="Unknown"].count())
print(test[test["var 1"]== 0].count())
```

The output is:

```
var 1    0
var 2    0
dtype: int64
var 1    0
var 2    0
dtype: int64
var 1    0
var 2    0
dtype: int64
var 1    1
var 2    1
dtype: int64
```

So for some reason Python is not counting the empty data as "". I then later use the following code to send the data back to a new csv file in hope that I can find out how to reference them.

The csv that I receive is shown as:

```
var 1
20.0
10.0
""
5.0
4.0
0.0
1.0
21.0
```

As you can see the data is sent back as "". I am trying to perform tasks based on the condition that the data == "", but obviously can't as the data is not being stored as "". Does anybody know how the data is stored?

All help is appreciated,

C.

Comment: You can simply `print(test)` and see what's used instead of the empty _string_ `""` in the data frame.

Comment: Lifesaver XD. It's being stored as NaN for some reason!

Comment: Missing data in pandas is represented by `NaN`. See [Working with missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html)

Comment: @Charmalade, see the description of `na_values` for the reason: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. How can I count the empty values? print(test[test["var 1"]== nan].count()) still returns 0 for me.

Comment: `NaN` will not equal `NaN` that is part of the definition. There is a method [`isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html#pandas-series-isna) that will tell you if a sell contains NaN or not. `df['var 1'].isna().sum()` can be used to "count" the number of Trues.

Comment: Ok thanks that worked for me. And lastly, how might I rewrite this line: test["var 1"].replace("", "Unknown", inplace=True) ? Don't worry: test["var 1"].replace(nan, "Unknown", inplace=True)  worked for me

Comment: `test['var 1'] = test['var 1'].fillna('Unknown')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is stored as a null value or `np.nan`. See the output of test dataframe when loaded:

```
test = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

    var 1   var 2
0   20.0    a
1   10.0    a
2   NaN     a
3   5.0     a
4   4.0     a
5   0.0     a
6   1.0     a
7   21.0    a
```

When you do `.to_csv()`, the null values become "" in Excel

So your code should be:

```
test = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
print(test[test["var 1"].isna()].count())
test["var 1"].replace(np.nan, "Unknown", inplace=True) 
print(test[test["var 1"].isna()].count())
print(test[test["var 1"]=="Unknown"].count())
print(test[test["var 1"]== 0].count()) 

var 1    0
var 2    1
dtype: int64
var 1    0
var 2    0
dtype: int64
var 1    1
var 2    1
dtype: int64
var 1    1
var 2    1
dtype: int64
```